# Python ORM for mongodb in django that doesnt use db.eval()

Tags: python, django, orm, mongodb

I am using a ExtJS frontend and for a back end I'm using django, mongodb, and mongoengine (ORM - between the two). Everything works until i decide to shard my mongo database, turns out db.eval() (uses datbase to run commands) doesn't work with a sharded database. So I have to switch out the ORM.

I found several other ORMS such as mongokit and mongoalchemy, however I do not want to go through each individual ORM and hope that it works after changing all the commands from the recent ORM to the new one. Does anyone know a Mongo ORM that doesn't use db.eval() or works with a sharded mongo database?

Thank you

Comment: What are you doing with `db.eval()`? There might be a way to refactor that code to work with a shared system...

Comment: So what db.eval() is basically using the another computer to compute the command. So you can do db.eval(1+1) and it returns two. It the same result just where it was computed is different. mongoengine in every command they use they run db.eval() so there is no way to get around it unless i completly rewrite their code.

Comment: I meant, what specific task are you trying to accomplish? `db.eval` will not work on sharded collections, but this is a limitation of MongoDB itself, not of Mongoengine. See [Sharding Limits](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Limits#ShardingLimits-db.evalDOCS%3AServersideCodeExecution) for details.

Comment: I understand that but Mongoengine is the middle layer between Django and Mongo and if Mongoengine uses a method that a sharded database cant use then it does not work. Im trying to find another ORM however i dont want to go through everyone and change all my code over and over again

Comment: MongoDB itself does not allow `db.eval` to be run against sharded collections. This is not a limitation of Mongoengine, but of MongoDB itself. Thus you won't be able to find an ORM/ODM which will let you do this. However, if you can describe what you ultimately want to accomplish, there may be another way to go about it that _will_ work on sharded collections.

Comment: So now I am confused but I'll try and answer. I am trying to create a webapp with a very data intense database. more than 80000 fields. So what i did Is I used EXTJS to creat the app, and Django to handle the webserver. Then i added a database (mongo) however i need Django and mongo to talk so i used a ORM. Now I needed to shard to have a quicker response to DJango. The orginal set up was ExtJS -> DJango -> mongoengine -> MongoDB. Now i am confused. MongoEngine does use db.eval() So initaily thought that i could find another ORM that doesnt use that.

Comment: So i want to search for 1 fields out of 80000 use map reduce find it and give back its details

Comment: Do you mean 80,000 documents, or documents which have 80,000 fields?

Comment: 80,000 fields (not exact but ruffly) but i mean like { 'name' : 'Computer 1' }

Comment: How many documents do you have/will you have? What are the fields and values? It seems likely that with a schema change and proper indexing you wouldn't need to shard to get good performance from MongoDB. If you can re-ask your question with details about what you're trying to accomplish, perhaps we can help you devise a strategy.

Comment: I dont know whether I am confusing or am just confused. But i really dont want another way to do it... I did speed tests with sharding and it goes alot faster, so I want sharding. However taking a look again mongoengine does use db.eval() and others do not so Im just going to go through each one. and hope they work

Comment: You realize that Mongoengine only uses `db.eval` for the `exec_js()` method, not for any others. If you don't use that in your own code, you can use Mongoengine just fine with sharding.

Comment: AFAIK mongoengine only uses db.eval if you call exec_js. Can you accomplish what you are trying to do without exec_js? This doesn't seem to be a mongoengine problem to me.

Comment: Alright Ill definitely try that... Thank you very much... Put it as an answer to that if it works I can give you points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoEngine has now been updated not to use `db.eval` for the 2 areas that used it where map_reduce should have been used: `sum` and `average`. `item_frequencies` has been updated to default to using map_reduce over using exec_js & `db.eval`.

In the end it was a small update: https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/pull/256/files thanks to @dcrosta for the patch and letting me know this thread existed!

You can grab the latest shard happy code from the dev branch https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/tree/dev

Dont forget theres a mailing list for monogoengine - http://groups.google.com/group/mongoengine-users for any comments / issues or feedback and theres #mongoengine on irc

Cheers,

Ross